# Murus internet sharing not working

Tags: macos, high-sierra, firewall, internet-sharing

I have Murus 1.4.12 and am following the directions to share my internet connection from `en0` (static IP connected to Comcast modem/router) through `en3`.  Both the client and server are macOS High Sierra 10.13.1.  I am successfully able to share it via `System Preferences -> Sharing`.  Regardless of Murus, I am able to use `en3` as a network device and ssh into the host over it -- just cannot share internet.

After resetting pf to its default state via Murus, installing boot scripts, and restarting, I create an NAT group with `10.0.0.25/32` (`en3`'s IP) with access to all services.  I then attempt to share internet connection from `en0` (WAN interface) to `en3`.

On the client machine with its own static IP of `10.0.0.234` and router of `10.0.0.25`, I am able to ping and ssh into `10.0.0.25` but do nothing else.  When I sniff `en3` via Murus I can see my attempts to `ping 8.8.8.8` but everything times out on the client.  The relevant pf rules Murus is generating are as follows:

```
table <NatLanInterfaces> { en3 }
pass net proto {tcp, udp} from {10.0.0.25/32 } to !<NATLanInterfaces> port {1:65535}
```

Can anyone see what I need to add or fix to let `10.0.0.234` access the WAN?

Comment: without seeing your pf rules, I would *guess* that you don't have a reverse route/rule set up allowing for responses to be sent back to the client.

Comment: @klanomath added -- 10.13.1

Comment: @Allan My rules are autogenerated by Murus.  What would that rule look like?  thanks!

Comment: @klanomath thanks ... I don't think this Comcast router lets me get that fancy but I will give it a shot.  amazon may be involved here.

Comment: @klanomath this is a Cisco DPC3941T.  Pretty sure Comcast has deliberately locked it down.

Comment: @klanomath indeed!  i heard rumors from a support tech about a super-secret way to get into the real interface and do it but it didn't work.  i'll just replace the modem and carry on.

Comment: @klanomath can you recommend a replacement modem / wired router?  i don't need wifi on it.

Comment: @WalrustheCat I tested Murus in an environment similar to yours and Internet Sharing works right out of the box (without static route on the "external" router). Did you add "all services" to the NAT group? The rule `pass net proto {tcp, udp} from {10.0.0.25/32 } to !<NATLanInterfaces` should end with `... port {1:65535}`!

Comment: @WalrustheCat Additionally your NAT group is faulty. The NAT group's IP-address/range should be `... from {10.0.0.234/32 } to ...`!

Comment: @klanomath it does sorry the error here is between the chair and the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set up is probably faulty. A static route on the second router (connected to the ISP) isn't required.

The proper set up looks like this:

- Open Murus and hit the wrench > Static NAT

[image]

- Choose the proper LAN and WAN interfaces. In your environment the WAN interface probably is en0 or en1 and your LAN interface is en3.
- Then move the mouse pointer to your NAT group and hit the looking glass:

  [image]

  Remove the current IP/network address (in your case 10.0.0.25/32) and add the "NAT-client's" IP address (in your case 10.0.0.234/32) or a network address (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24).

  You added the gateway's address (instead of the NATed network/host) by accident.

  Add "ALL SERVICES" to the *Allowed Internet Services*.
- Close the NAT window.
- In the menubar > Firewall > Interface Forwarding choose "Enable".
- In the upper right corner of Murus hit the start button (►) - just to be sure.
- Test the NAT with the client.

Comment: You have to remove the gateway's IP (10.0.0.25/32) from the NAT group. I'll check the ping problem (which is shouldn't be a NAT or a routing problem) later this evening (~next 60 mins).

Comment: @WalrustheCat Did you reboot the gateway (sometimes/often useful)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71155/discussion-between-klanomath-and-walrus-the-cat).