# How to install a DHCP server (wireless router or access point) downstream of Murus Static NAT internet sharing?

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing, ipfw

I am currently [sharing my Mac's ethernet connection via Murus static NAT](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309977/murus-internet-sharing-not-working).  Upstream I only have a cable modem, so the IP address of Mac #1 is my ISP-provided external IP.  I am running an ethernet USB adapter to another Mac and then using MacOS Internet Sharing from that machine to share the wired connection over its WiFi.  In other words, I am using Mac #2 as a wireless router.  This is less than optimal.

If I were to replace Mac #2 with a wireless router or access point, how would I configure that to use it seamlessly instead (have it do DHCP, etc, accept new devices without manual configuration.)

I just bought a wired switch and was really pleased by how it "just-works".  What is the fastest, no-nonsense way forward to a lightening fast wireless network here?

**output of `netstat -nr -f inet` on Mac #1 (Murus server):**

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            my.external.wan.1        UGSc           98   447794     en0
10/24              link#7             UCS             2        0     en3
10.0.0.24/32       link#7             UCS             1        0     en3
10.0.0.24          b4:9c:df:f0:dd:86  UHLWI           0       16     lo0
10.0.0.123         b4:9c:df:f0:85:3   UHLWIi          2   904865     en3    990
10.0.0.255         ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en3
my.external.wan/22       link#11            UCS             1        0     en0
my.external.wan.1/32     link#11            UCS             1        0     en0
my.external.wan.1        dc:eb:94:b5:cc:22  UHLWIir        28        0     en0    990
my.external.wan.70/32    link#11            UCS             1        0     en0
my.external.wan.70       a8:20:66:35:f:1d   UHLWI           0        1     lo0
my.external.wan.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1     1229     lo0
169.254            link#11            UCS             0        0     en0
169.254            link#7             UCSI            0        0     en3
224.0.0/4          link#11            UmCS            1        0     en0
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCSI           0        0     en3
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#11            UCS             0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCSI            0        0     en3
```

Comment: @klanomath seeing if you get this notification

Comment: oh, great!  can i get you on chat sometime?  i'm having some questions about said wired switch.

Comment: cool -- can you give me a link and a timerange when it's best to reach you?  dankeschon

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71216/macos-dhcp-server